# Difference between AddLoadEvent and function load of jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, load, onload-event

I'm trying find an explanation to the following question, I looked around and haven't found any awnser so far:  What is the the difference between the Simon Willison's code for the `AddLoadEvent` function and the `load` function from jQuery?

Here are the links:

1. `AddLoadEvent` code : http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/
2. `.load` function jQuery  see api load from jQuery

#### Case# 1 (jQuery .load function)

```
function replaceMissingImage(){
    //run code here...
}


$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
  replaceMissingImage();
});
```

#### or Case# 2 (AddEventLoad - JS)

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}


function replaceMissingImage(){
    //run code here...
}

addLoadEvent(replaceMissingImage);
```

Q: Would these two pieces of code do the same thing?

`$(window).load(function())` vs `AddLoadEvent`

Comment: Do you mean the jquery ready event?  Load is something different in jQuery

Comment: Yes i know about the Load in jQuery, but nope. i am not comparing the jQuery ready $(document).ready(function())" with the $(window).load. But instead the $(window).load and the Simon Willison's AddLoadEvent . Thank you

Comment: I think you meant `addLoadEvent(replaceMissingImage);` (note I removed parenthesis after `replaceMissingImage`), since you want to assign the function as the callback, not the result of executing that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that code does exact the same thing.  jQuery internally uses something very similiar to`addLoadEvent` to chain up functions, except it works for all kinds of events for all kinds of elements, not just `onload` of `window`.  It is largely based on [Dean Edwards' addEvent](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/) solution.  I'd recommend viewing the source of jQuery and searching for "edwards" to find this section of code; its flexibility is very impressive.

Comment: thank you very much. it's was very interessing to discover that Dean Edward's code hide behind jquery load.